# Как вывести все значения сущности

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Как вывести все сущности House? У нас есть House и репозиторий, с помощью которого можно их достать. Понимаю, что можно сделать вот так: `List<House> res = houseRepository.findAll();` А как мне их вернуть и каждый вывести? Не совсем понимаю.

```
@GetMapping("/list")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    public House userPostInfo() {
    List<House> res = houseRepository.findAll();
        return ??;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/list")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
public Collection<House> userPostInfo() {
   return houseRepository.findAll();
}
```